# i am webscraping with bs4 and the urls wont show up

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am new to webscaping and wanted to scape all the charackterportraits from the [lol site](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/) and when i examined one of the pictures in the browser it was in a "img scr="url" tag and i want to get the url to download the picture but when i do soup.select('img[src]') or soup.select('img') it returns an empty list and i dont know why

here is the code:

```
data=requests.get(website)
data.raise_for_status()


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text,"lxml")
print(soup)
#soup returns html    


elems = soup.select('img[src]')
print(elems)
#elems returns an empty list
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be possible to do with request, but it seems that your get request does not get the full pageSource.

You can overcome this issue using selenium to just get the content.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import bs4

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/')
page_source = driver.page_source
driver.close()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_source, "lxml")
print(soup)

elems = soup.find_all('img')
for elem in elems:
    print(elem.attrs['src'])
```

Output:

```
https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/img/champion/Aatrox.png
https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/img/champion/Ahri.png
https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/img/champion/Akali.png
https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/img/champion/Alistar.png
https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/img/champion/Amumu.png
https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/img/champion/Anivia.png
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the same endpoint the page does. Find it in network tab

```
import requests 

base = 'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/img/champion/'
r = requests.get('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.11.1/data/en_US/champion.json').json()
images = [base + r['data'][item]['image']['full'] for item in r['data']]
print(images)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/").text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('link')    #these are your tags eg: a , script link
```

```
OUTPUT:
Out[21]: 
[<a href="/en/game-info/get-started/">Get Started</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/get-started/what-is-lol/">What is League of Legends?</a>,
 <a href="https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/site/guide/index.html">New Player Guide</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/get-started/chat-commands/">Chat Commands</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/get-started/community-interaction/">Community Interaction</a>,
 <a href="/en/featured/summoners-code">The Summoner's Code</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/champions/">Champions</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/items/">Items</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/summoners/">Summoners</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/summoners/spells/">Summoner Spells</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/game-modes/">Game Modes</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/game-modes/summoners-rift/">Summoner's Rift</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/game-modes/the-twisted-treeline/">The Twisted Treeline</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/game-modes/howling-abyss/">Howling Abyss</a>,
 <a href="//na.leagueoflegends.com/en/">Home</a>,
 <a href="/en/game-info/">Game Info</a>]

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/").text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('script')
Out[22]: 
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/").text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('a')
[<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-N98J');</script>,
 <script>window.ga = window.ga || function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l = +new Date;</script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/lolkit/1.1.6/modernizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/lolkit/1.1.6/riot-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/lolkit/1.1.6/riot-kit-all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script type="text/javascript">rg_force_language = 'en_US';rg_force_manifest = 'https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/realms/na.js';rg_assets = 'https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/game-info/1.1.9';</script>,
 <script type="text/javascript">window.riotBarConfig = {touchpoints: {activeTouchpoint: 'game'},locale: {landingUrlPattern : 'https://na.leagueoflegends.com//game-info/'},footer: {enabled: true,container: {renderFooterInto: '#footer'}}};</script>,
 <script async="" src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/riotbar/prod/latest/en_US.js"></script>,
 <script src="https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/dragonhead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/riot-dd-utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/riot-dd-i18n.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/external/jquery.lazy-load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/DDFilterApp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/DDMarkupItem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/DDMarkupContainer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/champions/ChampionsListGridItem.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/champions/ChampionsListGridView.js" type="text/javascript"></script>,
 <script src="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/js/champions/ChampionsListApp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>]

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/").text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('link')
Out[23]: 
[<link href="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/lolkit/1.1.6/lol-kit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>,
 <link href="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/frontpage/apps/prod/LolGameInfo-Harbinger/en_US/0d258ed5be6806b967afaf2b4b9817406912a7ac/assets/assets/css/base-styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>,
 <link href="https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/lolkit/1.1.6/resources/images/favicon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON"/>]
```